# Should MapView be View or ViewGroup in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, customization

In the past month, I had written an app using map API ,such as Google Map api and other apis in my country.They are encapsulated well and easy to use.Then I want to figure out how the api was built and organized.

In the process,I found three open source projects meet my need ,osmand,mapsforge and osmdroid.With my study going on, a few questions came to me.

[image: help for explanation]

The picture is a screenshot of google map app on Android,it shows a base map ,some markers and an information window.
As we all know , users can touch marker and information window,and they can response to the touch gesture.

---

Here comes the first question.

**1.Are marker and information window View/ViewGroup or picture elements which are just drawn on the base map?Which choice is better?**

- In osmand, marker is picture element while  information window is a custom dialog.

[image: osmand]

- In mapsforge ,there is only marker and the marker is a picture element.

[image: mapsforge]

- In osmdroid, they are both picture elements.

[image: osmdroid]

---

As for the touch event for the marker and information window.

- In osmand ,user can long touch on the map and the information window will appear.User can also touch the window to do further things.When long touch event activated,one of a layers will intercept the event and dispatch it through those abstract layer until meet the specific layer which can consume it.After a complex calculation and process, the information window will appear on that point.Marker can be put later and it doesn't response to touch.
- mapsforge haven't implement touch event for marker.
- as for osmdroid , I have't digged into it.

The touch event handle of marker and information window of these three doesn't implement as complete as google map api and other apis I used before.

---

Here is what I think?

If they are view, MapView should be ViewGroup or be a combination of container(ViewGroup) and BaseMap(View).

- benefit:maybe it is easier to handle the touch event.
- shortcoming:the relative relation between MapView and them should be well considered when map moves.

If they are picture elements,MapView can just be View (or ViewGroup).

- benefit:the relative relation talked above is not that a problem
- shortcoming:the touch event should be well calculated and handled.

For now:

- [MapView in Mapsforge is ViewGroup](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/OsmAnd/src/net/osmand/plus/views/OsmandMapTileView.java)
- [OsmandMapTileView which is similar to MapView in Osmand is SurfaceView](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/OsmAnd/src/net/osmand/plus/views/OsmandMapTileView.java)
- [MapView in osmdroid is ViewGroup](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java)

So here comes the second question：

**2.How should we choose the base class combination of Marker and MapView? What are benefits and shortcomings of each combination ?**

[Discussion in mapsforge google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mapsforge-dev/gvoMh5jhm5E)

***I'd appreciate it if you share your thoughts!***